# Posts per page for desktop and for mobile separetely in Blogger template

Tags: blogger

How can I set posts per page for desktop view and for mobile view separately in Blogger template? Currently I set 1 post per page in post widget in Layout, this is also applied to mobile view. However I want 5 posts per page for mobile.

Comment: Any chance to share a bit code and tell us what you have tried so far such as reading the documentation or searching the web?

Comment: I have added <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost == &quot;true&quot;'>...<b:if> in post widget to hide following 4 posts in desktop view. This works fine, however in the pager widget next/prev links point to 5 newer/older posts instead the adjacent posts.